# Add element in table in PHP

Tags: php, html

In a script to manage results of students in a school, I would like to add two elements in a table. Datas get with a validation a form.

For exemple, this table is display

```
echo '<td> <select name="'.$ligne1['ID_ELEVE'].$cpt.'">';
                echo '<option value="'.$tabNotesG[$i][2].'">'.$tabNotesG[$i][2].'</option>';
                for ($k = 1; $k <= 6; $k = $k + 0.5) {
                    echo '<option value="'.$k.'">'.$k.'</option>';
                }
                echo '</select> </td>';         
                echo '<td> <input type="TEXT" name="date'.$ligne1['ID_ELEVE'].$cpt.'" value="'.$ligne2['DATENOTE'].'"/> </td>';
```

After the validation, I would to add all input in a table:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($tabId); $i++) {
        for($j = 0; $j < $nbTests; $j++){
            $tabComplet[$tabId[$i]][$j] = $_REQUEST[$tabId[$i].$j];
            $tabComplet[$tabId[$i]][$j] = $_REQUEST['date'.$tabId[$i].$j];
        }
    }
```

This code save only date field and I would like to save results and date on after the other (for exemple, table = results1,date1,result2,date2,result3,date3).

How do you do this?

Thanks for help in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add another dimension to store every data on after the other

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($tabId); $i++) {
    for($j = 0; $j < $nbTests; $j++){
        $tabComplet[$tabId[$i]][$j][] = $_REQUEST[$tabId[$i].$j];
        $tabComplet[$tabId[$i]][$j][] = $_REQUEST['date'.$tabId[$i].$j];
    }
}
```

That will give you a 3 dimensional array like this

```
$tabComplet : Array (
    $tabId[$i] : Array ( // for $i < count($tabId)
        $j : Array ( // for $j < $nbTests
            0 => first result
            1 => first date
            2 => second result
            3 => second date
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: Is it a table with three dimensions ?

Comment: @Sab25 I updated my answer to give you the structure of result array